# How do you add a custom HTTP response header in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-headers

I'm looking to add custom HTTP response headers to a Ruby on Rails app that is currently hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Use:

```
response.headers['HEADER NAME'] = 'HEADER VALUE'
```

either in a specific method or to a before_filter method of your application controller depending on whether you need this to be added in a specific or to all of your responses.

### UPDATE for Rails 5 - February 24th, 2018

As noted by @BrentMatzelle in the comments, for [**Rails 5**](https://iridakos.com/how-to/2018/03/27/custom-http-headers):

```
response.set_header('HEADER NAME', 'HEADER VALUE')
```

Comment: Make sure that the value you set is a string, otherwise pow will give you strange errors

Comment: To add this to all actions in the controller use a `after_action`.

Comment: This is not correct. You should not really access the response object. See instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743475/1028679 and read the the comments!

Answer (score 24):

In rails 5, the following solution works (in action methods)

```
response.set_header("Header-Name", "Header value")
```

Reference: [edgeapi](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html#method-i-set_header)

Answer (score 23):

In Rails 3 or above, simply

```
headers['Header-Name'] = 'header value'
```

works in controllers. This is even *the* recommended way; according to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html),

> Response is mostly a Ruby on Rails framework implementation detail, and should never be used directly in controllers. Controllers should use the methods defined in `ActionController::Base` instead. For example, if you want to set the HTTP response’s content MIME type, then use `ActionController::Base#headers` instead of `Response#headers`.

And [this is still true in Rails 7.0](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html).

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Still most people ignore the documentation and use `response` object.

Comment: I don't understand the issue with using response, even the guides say "If you want to set custom headers for a response then response.headers is the place to do it." and headers are delegated from action controller to response.  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L150

Comment: @fatfrog I think this is called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). Using the public interface is more robust, even if it simply delegates to a private interface; for example, in future the Rails team might want to add something in the `headers` method, which breaks you if you directly access the `response`. This is no new concept; in Java, many public `getFoo()` methods simply get you the private variable `this.foo`.

Answer (score 9):

In rails 4, set the response headers in the application.rb or respective environment files. Once you done that, you can override the header value wherever you required in the controller. Refer this [url](http://chriszetter.com/blog/2013/10/04/setting-headers-in-rails-4/) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

If your headers are static, e.g. your own custom Server header, you can simply update `config.action_dispatch.default_headers`. The following example sets a custom [Server header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server); add it to your `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/...`:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers["Server"] = "MyServer/#{config.version}"
```

(Assuming you set `config.version` earlier)

For more, see [Rails Guides: Configuring Rails Applications: Configuring Action Dispatch](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch):

> `config.action_dispatch.default_headers` is a hash with HTTP headers that are set by default in each response.

This will be less work each request than running a controller callback.

NB: For more than one header use `merge!` to not remove existing essential XSS etc headers.

Answer (score 4):

In rails 4 works following:

```
class API::V1::BaseController 
  after_action :set_version_header

  protected
    def set_version_header
        response.headers['X-ComanyName-Api-Version'] = 'V1'
    end
end
```