# Render JSON with header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, cors

I want to render JSON with the following `cors` header in my controller:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' = '*'.
```

I tried this:

```
def my_action
  render(json: some_params)
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
end
```

but I got an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`. Are there ways to render JSON with headers?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't set a header after render, because the response is sent. So change the headers after makes no sense and you get this error.

Try:

```
def my_action
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  render(json: some_params)
end
```

**UPDATE FOR RAILS 5**

As pointed in the question [How do you add a custom http header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654052/how-do-you-add-a-custom-http-header), after rails 5 you should be setting the headers as following:

```
response.set_header('HEADER NAME', 'HEADER VALUE')
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that you are rendering the response and then sending the headers.
You should **never** set headers after the response is sent.

`render` should be, usually, the last line of your *action*.

```
def my_action
  ...
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  render json: some_params
end
```