# Render JSON from hash with headers

Tags: ruby, json, api

I need to add a header to my hash that I convert to JSON.

In my controller I have:

```
render json: @rates
```

With `@rates` being a hash that looks like this:

```
{:rates=>[{:service_name=>"Standard", :service_code=>"FU", 
:total_price=>"1100", :currency=>"USD", :min_delivery_date=>"2016-03-11 
08:00:00 +0000", :max_delivery_date=>"2016-03-16 06:59:59 +0000"}, 
{:service_name=>"Priority", :service_code=>"FU", :total_price=>"2300", 
:currency=>"USD", :min_delivery_date=>"2016-03-08 08:00:00 +0000", 
:max_delivery_date=>"2016-03-09 07:59:59 +0000"}, 
{:service_name=>"Expedited", :service_code=>"FU", :total_price=>"1420", 
:currency=>"USD", :min_delivery_date=>"2016-03-09 08:00:00 +0000", 
:max_delivery_date=>"2016-03-10 07:59:59 +0000"}]}
```

The JSON format is perfect, but I believe I need a header for it for the API to get the rates from me. I saw "[Render JSON with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318324/render-json-with-header)", but I don't get it.

I need to add:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Can I just add this to my hash as another key/value pair? Or do I have to do some special header value?

Comment: `render json: @rates` will set the content type automatically. You do not need to do anything.

Comment: Yea.. I'm obviously doing something wrong, because I get that weird header.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the content_type option.

```
render json: @rates, content_type: "application/json"
```

Comment: tried but no luck.. I wish there was some service that I could post my JSON too and the API could hit it and see if it right.. Anyone know of anything out there?

Comment: I found it!! this is the service I've been looking for: [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/)

Comment: But Hurl.it requires your application to be publicly accessible. If you are developing JSON endpoints and testing locally, you can just use Postman. http://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: oh man! that's even better.. Thank you! I just need to be able to see what the heck is going on.. I am developing on Cloud9 and I'm starting to think it has something to do with that..