# Setting HTTP response headers application-wide in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-3.2, response-headers

How do I set response headers application-wide in Rails 3.2?

The Rails guides to security for [4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.8/security.html) mentions `config.action_dispatch.default_headers`:

> 8 Default Headers
>
> Every HTTP response from your Rails application receives the following
>   default security headers.
>
> ```
> config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
>   'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
>   'X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block',
>   'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff'
> }
> ```
>
> You can configure default headers in `config/application.rb`.
>
> ```
> config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
>   'Header-Name' => 'Header-Value',
>   'X-Frame-Options' => 'DENY'
> }
> ```

but I couldn't find anything about application-wide configuration of headers in the security guide for Rails [3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/security.html#header-injection), or anything relevant in the [configuring](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/configuring.html) guide for Rails 3.2. The answers in [How do you add a custom http header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654052/how-do-you-add-a-custom-http-header) seem to either be addressing versions of Rails more recent than 3.2, or modify responses in controllers rather than application wide.