# Catching 301 redirection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are certain cases in which we are doing a 301 redirect for pages from the controller. `redirect_to product_show_path(updated_id)`, status: :moved_permanently. These redirections are working but we want to setup a custom meta tag when user is landing on a page by a 301 redirect. Is there any way to know it globally that is set it in the `application.html.erb` file?

Comment: Maybe you can use `request.referrer` in landing controller?

Comment: How can that help me in differentiating between a 301 and just regular page href?

Comment: I do not know how works you app, but if you can landing from other page maybe is not the correct method. Other options are [set-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654052/how-do-you-add-a-custom-http-header)  or with [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

Answer (score 1):

Use [query string parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to send additional data with a GET request (a 301 Redirect is always a GET request).

```
redirect_to product_show_path(updated_id, redirected_from: URI.encode(request.original_url))
```

This creates a param in the params hash just like any other:

```
<%= if params[:redirected_from].present? %>
   You where redirected from <%= URI.decode(params[:redirected_from]) %>
<% end %>
```

This unlike the `HTTP_REFERER` header works in all browsers.

Comment: Not 100% sure that you need to `URI.encode` the value or if rails does it automatically.